# What is actually use of non escaping closures?

Tags: swift, closures

If a function can return a value itself then why need to call non escaping closure to return value? 
Consider following example

```
 func add(a: Int, b: Int, completion: (Int) -> ()) {
        let addition = a + b
        completion(addition)
 }
```

Comment: You can pass the closure around to people that would not otherwise know how to invoke the function.

Comment: In your example, maybe the caller of `add` (let's call it `foo`) has no idea what the `completion` does. `foo` just received it (as a closure) from somewhere else. And the caller of `foo` knows what the completion callback should do, but has no business calling `add` directly. Maybe it is something like `foo(listOfManyNumbersToFold, printResultCompletion)`

Answer (score 2):

For example, `a` and `b` parameters must be a positive numbers by some reason. There are 3 way to workaroud this case:

1) You can add this check in a function that calls `add`. If you do so you will repeat this code any time before `add` calling. It's a bad idea because of code duplication; 2) You can add this check in the `add` method and return an error to a closure. In any closure you have to handle this error even if you don't want to execute any code at this case. So it's not a good idea too; 3) You can add this check in the `add` method and return a boolean value showing a correctness of parameters. If parameters is correct you calculate a result and call the closure like in this code:

```
func add(a: Int, b: Int, completion: (Int) -> ()) -> Bool {
    guard a > 0, b > 0 else {
      return false
    }

    let addition = a + b
    completion(addition)

    return true
}

if !add(a: someA, b: someB, completion: {sum in print(sum)}) {
  print("Wrong numbers!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Common use cases for closure are:

1. Asynchronous calls; networking.
2. Functions stored as variables; think actions and supplied callbacks.
3. Scheduling tasks on a dispatch queue.

If there is a process where it take sometime to get work done and give back result. In these cases closure are best options.

**Non Escaping Closures**

Non-escaping closures have a very clear lifecycle and have become the default closure type in Swift 3 because of it. A non-escaping closure is simple: It’s passed into a function (or other containing scope), the function/scope executes that closure, and the function returns. The closure cannot return or finish executing after the body of the calling function has returned. Due to that fact, the compiler is able to optimize non-escaping closures over escaping closures.

**Default closure behaviour (non-escaping)**

Say for a simple function with closure like this :

```
func macICanBuy(budget: Int, closure: (String) -> Void) {
  print("checking budget...")

  closure("Mcdonalds' Big Mac")

  print("macICanBuy finished execution")
}

override func viewDidLoad(){
  macICanBuy(budget: 100, closure: { mac in
    print("I can afford a \(mac)")
  })
}

// output: 
// checking budget...
// I can afford a Mcdonalds' Big Mac
// macICanBuy finished execution
```

Before the app executes the macICanBuy function, it will load the passed parameter (budget and closure) into the phone memory (RAM) so the function can use these data.

After the app finish execute the macICanBuy function, the app no longer needs the budget and closure data, hence it will remove them from the memory. The closure data didn't manage to escape from being removed from memory after the function has finished executing, hence it is called 'non-escaping' closure.

**Above reference from:**

https://fluffy.es/what-is-escaping-closure/

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But my question is if we consider above example we can simply return a value from function then why someone can use non-escaping closure? In which scenario we should use non-escaping closure instead of returning value from a function?

Comment: @PankajBattise is this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is not much difference between a function with a return value and non-escaping closure.
It's more about a syntax choice.

The main use case is to use them as escaping for async calls.
However, if you want to work with a return value inside another inner scope then non-escaping closure fits that well.